# Unable to parse function with Esprima/Acorn: unexpected token '('

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, esprima

I am able to parse arrow functions using Esprima and Acorn, but using normal functions gives an error:

```
const esprima = require('esprima');
const acorn = require('acorn');

console.log(esprima.parseScript(` () => { console.log('Test')}`)); //works
console.log(acorn.parse(` () => { console.log('Test') }`); //works

console.log(esprima.parseScript(`function () { console.log('Test')}`)); // Unexpected token
console.log(acorn.parse(`function () { console.log('Test') }`); //Unexpected token
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## tl;dr

If the line begins with the token `function`, it is a [*FunctionDeclaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions), not a [*FunctionExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functions-and-classes). And a function declaration [requires an identifier](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) (in a *FunctionExpression* [it is optional](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions)).

## --------

The way that `function () { console.log('Test') }` code is written, makes it a [**function declaration** (*FunctionDeclaration*)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions), not a function expression. And a function declaration expects an identifier (in a function expression [it is optional](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions)).

Try it in Chrome console, you'll get the same error.

To understand, you'll have to look into [the grammar os ES6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) (more below).

The `() => {}` ([*ArrowFunction*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions)) is **always** an expression (specifically, believe it or not, an [*AssignmentExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators)).

---

A JavaScript, in ES6, [*Script*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules) is roughly a sequence of statements ([*StatementList*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block), which is a sequence of [*StatementListItem*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block)s).

A [*StatementListItem*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-block) is a [*Statement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) or a [*Declaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations).

Between [*Statement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) or a [*Declaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations), the only possible expression is 
[*ExpressionStatement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-statement).

[*ExpressionStatement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-statement) is nothing more than an [*Expression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-rules).

And in [*Expression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-expression-rules) you find the [*FunctionExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functions-and-classes).

Because they start with the same token, I believe the [*FunctionDeclaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) takes precedence over the [*FunctionExpression*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functions-and-classes) (the former is "less deep" down the grammar). So the parser consumes the token `function` an expects the [*FunctionDeclaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions) to continue, throwing the error.

### Getting rid of the error

You can add an identifier, fulfilling the [*FunctionDeclaration*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions)'s requirements:

```
console.log(esprima.parseScript(`function test() { console.log('Test')}`));
console.log(acorn.parse(`function test() { console.log('Test') }`);
```

But, again, that makes it a FunctionDeclaration. To make your code a function expression alone, as pointed by [@JaredSmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3757232/jared-smith) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564001/unable-to-parse-function-with-esprima-acorn-unexpected-token/49564052#comment86136996_49564052), wrap it into `(`/`)`s:

```
console.log(esprima.parseScript(`(function () { console.log('Test')} )`));
console.log(acorn.parse(`(function () { console.log('Test') } )`);
```

Comment: Thanks, so adding a name to the function "function test () { console.log('Test') }" makes it into an expression?

Comment: Makes it into a declaration statement, a [*FunctionStatement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-definitions).

Comment: @amp you need to make it an *expression*: something that evaluates to a *value*. `(function() {})` is an expression, `function () {}` is a statement. Neither one have names.